# How do I update my react app code after deployment?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, hosting, npm-run

I create build of my React app. Then i was deploy the app on hostinger server. Now I want to change something in my react app code. So after change the code I need to rebuild my react app? And Push that build folder on hostinger again?

I want to know how to update react app code after deploy build folder on hostinger?